# JqueryUI autocomplete barcode scanner with delay on enter key press

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, point-of-sale

I'm looking to use the skill_input field for accomplishing field to read from barcode scanner or to be used also keyboard incase the item doesn't have barcode to be scanned,
I have an issue, the barcode scanner usually scan code and do enter key(automatically configured)
So when i read code fast and click enter , already the list of items isn't been loaded yet,
It needs like 1 second to load the list , so im thinking in a way of delaying the enter key press

```
$(function() {

     $("#skill_input").autocomplete({
        source: "fetchData.php",
        minLength: 3,
        autoFocus: true,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            //copy id and desc of the array (item)to another field
            $("#code").val(ui.item.id); 
            $("#item_description").val(ui.item.value);  
            $("#skill_input").val("");
        },
        response: function( event, ui ) {
                
            $("#skill_input").keydown(function(e) {
                if(e.which == 13) {
                        setTimeout( function()  {

                            if($("#skill_input").val().length>0) {  // if not empty
                                insert_row();
                            }
                        }, 2000);
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });     //  alert(event);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: And what's your question about this? Why is this tagged with PHP and MySQL, but does not contain any such code?

Comment: fetchData.php is processed through php & Mysql , it just extract the rows(items) id and description for items and store display into Json , and it is generated by the text field skill_input field

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. If this **really** is a PHP or MySQL related problem, why haven't you shared any code?

Comment: Which is the slow part?  That Jquery stuff?  The PHP code?  The MySQL `SELECT`?